# AngularJS: Angular Material Virtual Repeat & md-list

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am experiencing strange behavior when using the virtual repeat along with the md-list.  Here is my issue as outlined on GitHub:

***Actual Behavior:***

**What is the issue? ***

Not all items are being rendered on md-list when list is implemented as md-virtual-repeat-container.

**What is the expected behavior?**

I expected that all items be rendered.

**CodePen Demo which shows your issue:**

http://codepen.io/frikkievb/pen/VKbEXZ

**Details:** I found that certain values are not being rendered on the md-list. On my side it is usually items starting on the 0 index of each page.

***Angular Versions:***

**Angular Version:** 1.5.5

**Angular Material Version:** v1.1.1

**Browser Type: *** Chrome

**Browser Version: *** 53.0.2785.116 m

**OS: *** Windows 10

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyAppController as ctrl" ng-cloak="" class="virtualRepeatdemoDeferredLoading" ng-app="MyApp">

  <md-content layout="column">
    <div ui-view="projectContent">

      <md-list md-virtual-repeat-container style="height:500px">
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line" md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.items" md-on-demand ng-click="ctrl.edit()">
          Item: {{item}}
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </div>


</div>
```

**JavaScript**

/**
 * Created by frikk on 2016/08/01.
 */

```
(function () {

    function MyAppController() {

        var vm = this;
        vm.edit = edit;

        vm.items = {

            pages: [],
            pageSize: 10,
            getItemAtIndex: function (index) {

                var pageNumber = Math.floor(index / this.pageSize);
                var page = this.pages[pageNumber];
                if (page) {
                    return page[index % this.pageSize];
                } else if (page !== null) {
                    this.fetchPage(pageNumber);
                }
            },
            getLength: function () {
                return 50;
            },
            fetchPage: function (pageNumber) {
                this.pages[pageNumber] = null;
                var pageOffset = pageNumber * this.pageSize;
                this.pages[pageNumber] = [];
                for (var i = pageOffset; i < pageOffset + this.pageSize; i++) {
                    this.pages[pageNumber].push(i);
                }
            }
        }



        function edit() {

        }
    }

    angular.module("MyApp",[
      "ngAria",
      "ngAnimate",
        "ngMessages",
        "ngMaterial",
    ])
        .controller("MyAppController", [MyAppController]);
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very unusual problem that I've partially fixed - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VKzVma?editors=1010#0)

Following on from the examples in the [demos](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) I introduced a $timeout in fetchPage. This solves the problem of not displaying all the items. However, you will notice a slight delay displaying some items initially.

JS

```
(function () {
    MyAppController.$inject = ["$timeout"];

    function MyAppController($timeout) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.items = {

        pages: [],
        pageSize: 10,
        temp: [],
        getItemAtIndex: function (index) {

          var pageNumber = Math.floor(index / this.pageSize);
          var page = this.pages[pageNumber];
          if (page) {
            return page[index % this.pageSize];
          } else if (page !== null) {
            this.fetchPage(pageNumber);
          }
        },
        getLength: function () {
          return 50;
        },
        fetchPage: function (pageNumber) {
          var pageOffset = pageNumber * this.pageSize;
          this.pages[pageNumber] = [];
          this.temp = [];
          for (var i = pageOffset; i < pageOffset + this.pageSize; i++) {
            this.temp.push(i);
          }
          $timeout(angular.noop).then(angular.bind(this, function () {
            this.pages[pageNumber] = this.temp;
          }));
        }
      }
    }

    angular.module("MyApp",[
      "ngAria",
      "ngAnimate",
      "ngMessages",
      "ngMaterial",
    ])
      .controller("MyAppController", MyAppController);
})()
```

Comment: Thank you camden_kid.  I will try using this workaround.  I experienced the initial problem while trying to bind it to a remote source.  Will check if this might solve that problem as well.